# How to convert strings to raw strings in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mathjax

I have this string which has mathjax equations, which has many backslashes and I have to include them to display the content properly.

But strings in dart are considering backslashes as escape sequences and not the part of the string.

When (a \ne 0), there are two solutions to (ax^2 + bx + c = 0) and they are
[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.]

So how we can convert string to raw string in dart.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax example</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are 
\[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html code which I want to run in my webview but the string above mentioned needs to be converted to raw string to properly render it in dart

If we don't convert it into raw string it consider the backslash() as a escape sequence character.

Comment: Post the code you already have so we can better assist you

Answer (score 2):

In Dart, a raw string can be created by prepending an r to a string:

```
String str1 = r'This is a raw string, this \ here does not do any escaping';
```

Comment: But if I have a string which is stored in a variable, then how can we convert that string into a raw string in dart

Comment: If it's already in a variable it's already correct. backslashes only mess up if you manually type it in your dart code.

Comment: Ivo is right: if you already have backslashes in your `String` variable then you don't have to do anything

Comment: I want to say is,I am getting data from the api which are questions which will contain this matjax equations so will it work fine.

Comment: Dart will not consider the backslashes in the data as escape sequence character backslash(\) ?

Comment: no it will not consider

Comment: ok will try it and inform